# Virtual backgrounds for any videoconferencing or webcam application

Tags: hardware, video, camera, video-conference

I assume the answer is no, but does macOS provide a way (or is it **feasible** via user application software) to enable (force) the use (via **software** from a **single application**) of e.g. a *custom* **virtual background** for **any** (**all**) videoconferencing applications that may access the front camera?

I assume the answer depends on what means MacOS provides to application developers for managing the **video stream**. But for example, can one user application in macOS **modify** the video stream for all other user applications? (e.g. assuming already that macOS does **not** provide **itself** an end-user friendly interface to define virtual backgrounds).

By virtual background I am referring to the ability of customizing the background on a video call so that people can see the person looking at the camera in front of the camera, but the user can use a e.g. static picture or animation for the background. Examples include [this feature](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/microsoft-teams-now-lets-you-use-custom-backgrounds-during-video-calls/) supported from Microsoft Teams, or [this one](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/210707503-Virtual-Background) from Zoom.

Comment: Right now a simple "yes" or "no" can answer the question. Can you be a bit more specific about what you are looking for here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is yes. Applications can create a virtual camera, which other applications will have available in exactly the same way they have the built-in camera on a laptop available, or a USB-connected camera for example.

The application would need to read the images from your real camera, insert your virtual background, and then expose it as a virtual camera.

For example see virtual webcams such as: [OBS Virtual Camera](https://github.com/johnboiles/obs-mac-virtualcam) or [Webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io).

If you combine the OBS Virtual Camera program with [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/da), you can use the green screen (chroma key) features to get the setup you're looking for.